# Bind caps lock key to tmux prefix on macos sierra

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

Before I upgraded to macos sierra I was able to bind my caps lock key to the `Ctrl-b`/`C-b` keystroke to act as a single key for triggering the tmux prefix by using [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en). Unfortunately, Seil doesn't work with sierra yet.

How do I map a single key e.g., caps lock, to a keystroke combination on macos sierra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install [Karabiner-Elements latest build](https://pqrs.org/latest/karabiner-elements-latest.dmg) ([source](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements)).
2. Turn off the default caps lock functionality in System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys... by setting Caps Lock to 'No Action'. [image]
3. Map caps lock to a key you don't use in Karabiner-Elements e.g., `F1`. [image: map caps lock in Karabiner-Elements]
4. Assuming you're using iTerm, map the new caps lock key destination (in our example `F1`) to the hex code value of your tmux prefix (by default the tmux prefix is `Ctrl-b`/`C-b`, but if it's not, here's [a table of hex codes](http://www.nthelp.com/ascii.htm)). [image]

You should now be able to hit caps lock key to trigger your tmux leader key.